# Adding New Time slots to Time slots table

Tags: mysql, if-statement, join, sql-order-by, workbench

I am working on party booking system where user can schedule his party by entering time slot. if user enters time slot which is between the existing time slot then that should not be added.
For Example:we have 10:00 Am to 12:00 PM a booking and if new user need to book a party then the time slot table should not accept  time between 10:00 am to 12:00 PM and it also should not accept 9:30 am to   11:00 am and also should not accept 10:00 am to 12:30 Pm and also 10:00 am to 11:00 am

Comment: you want to do this in sql ?

Comment: I need it in  MySQL

Answer (score 0):

you should use two columns in your table one for the start time and one for the end ,

```
//get this values from the db using a select statement
$start=$_POST['start_time']

$end=$_POST['end_time']
//get id from db using select statement 
$id=$_POST['id']



INSERT INTO table_party(start_time, end_time)
SELECT id FROM table_party
WHERE id='$id AND (start_time BETWEEN $start AND DATE_SUB($start,INTERVAL 30 MINUTE ))
AND (end_time BETWEEN $END AND DATE_SUB($end,INTERVAL 60 MINUTE ));
```

Comment: what is this table party belong to?

Comment: i just used table_party as an example , you can use whatever table name you have used in your database , its the table where the user inserts his scheduled times into

Comment: INSERT INTO mtimeslot(Start Time, End Time)
SELECT TimeSlotID FROM mtimeslot
WHERE TimeSlotID='$TimeSlotID' AND (TIME( STR_TO_DATE( Start Time, '%h:%i %p' )) BETWEEN TIME( STR_TO_DATE( Start Time, '%h:%i %p' )) AND DATE_SUB(TIME( STR_TO_DATE( Start Time, '%h:%i %p' )),INTERVAL 30 MINUTE ))
AND (TIME( STR_TO_DATE(EndTime, '%h:%i %p' )) BETWEEN TIME( STR_TO_DATE(End Time, '%h:%i %p' )) AND DATE_SUB(TIME( STR_TO_DATE(End Time, '%h:%i %p' )),INTERVAL 60 MINUTE ))
and Party ID=15
and Party Area ID=8
and Org ID=100;

Comment: if i use the above code it is not accepting any timeslot

Comment: you need to add party id into all your tables , use the format  tablename.column to link your tables , meaning like if party area is from another table and org is from another , you could say , WHERE   table1.partyid=table2.partyid AND table3.partyid=table1.partyid

Comment: //get this values from the db using a select statement
$start=$_POST['start_time']

$end=$_POST['end_time']
//get id from db using select statement 
$id=$_POST['id']

INSERT INTO mtimeslot(start time, end time) SELECT TimeSlotID FROM mtimeslot WHERE Party ID=15 AND (start time BETWEEN $start AND DATE_SUB($start,INTERVAL 30 MINUTE )) AND (end_time BETWEEN $END AND DATE_SUB($end,INTERVAL 60 MINUTE ));